# What's up with CollaborationGroupFeed?

Tags: community, feeditem, chatter-groups

We're trying to display `FeedItems` for a Chatter group to our external users on a Community site.
The obvious thing is to use the built in Feed component in the Builder. But that is disappointingly non-customizable.
So we're building a Lightning component. It should be relatively simple:
`@AuraEnabled` function to `SELECT Id, InsertedById, InsertedBy.Name, Body, LikeCount, CommentCount, CreatedDate FROM FeedItem WHERE ParentId = <GroupId>`.
And it mostly works.
However, a community user (not me, the admin) cannot see the `FeedItems`.
Eventually I found an old forum post saying we need to perform the exact same query, but on the `CollaborationGroupFeed` object.
So that's cool.

But I can't find any documentation about this object. Also, for some reason the `IsClosed` field doesn't exist on `CollaborationGroupFeed` ...?
Also it appears that queries to `FeedItem` and `CollaborationGroupFeed` return the exact same record. Down to the `Id`. So why can't I see the `IsClosed` field on `CollaborationGroupFeed`?

Where can I find what fields exist on this object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FeedItem represents an entry in the feed, such as changes in a record feed, including text posts, link posts, and content posts. This object is available in API version 21.0 and later. This object replaces FeedPost.

- It is not limited to any Object. When you do a post in group, you can
  see it by querying on both Feeditem and CollaborationGroupFeed object.
- But, when you do post on Account record chatter, it can be queried
  using feeditem and Accountfeed but not on CollaborationGroupFeed .

> Id of the post in a group queried using feedItem and CollaborationGroupFeed 
>   will be same.

If you are using API version 23.0 or later and have **View All Data** permission, you can directly query for a FeedItem.

So, CollaborationGroupFeed is limited to chatterpost related with a collaboration group whereas feeditem is generic feed object.

**IsClosed** is not available on CollaborationGroupFeed, it is only available in FeedItem Object.

Comment: Where are you quoting from? What other fields are not available on `CollaborationGroupFeed`? How can I tell if this post is closed or not?

Comment: You ca check it in your developer console. click on file--> open resource--> search for Collaborationgroupfeed. You will get all the fields available.